# Any alternatives to Rails pessimist locking + Mysql?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following code inside a Rails model:

```
self.with_lock do
  # Lots of code
end
```

Which generates a SELECT FOR UPDATE query.

I realized that it's working in my production environment. After reviewing mysql manual, i found the following information:

```
Locking of rows for update using SELECT FOR UPDATE only applies when autocommit is disabled
```

As expected, autocommit is ON in my production environment.

What options do i have?

I can't disable autocommit because an PHP application in the same server depends on it. I also need a lock in this code because it's causing problems with concurrent connections.

I couldn't find any Gem or something that could help me with it. Like locking with files in a temporary folder. Will i need to code it on my own?

Answer (score 1):

yeah, but the rest of that sentence you copied from the manual reads:

```
...(either by beginning transaction with START TRANSACTION or by setting autocommit to 0. If autocommit is enabled, the rows matching the specification are not locked.
```

So, all you need to do is start a transaction, and autocommit will be disabled.  Which is exactly what you are doing.

You can't find a gem that does what you want because Rails is already doing it.

You can confirm that Rails is doing the right thing by tailing the logs and making sure the `SELECT FOR UPDATE` comes inside a transaction block.